# Can async_write cause segmentation fault when this is deleted?

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, boost-asio

I am using Boost to send data over TCP with `async_write`:

`std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>::iterator> iter = std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>::iterator>(this->m_vDataToWrite.begin());`

```
boost::asio::async_write(this->socket_, boost::asio::buffer(*message),
    boost::asio::transfer_all(), boost::bind(&Session::writeHandler,
           this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
           boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred(),
           message, 
           iter
           ));



    // ...

    void Session::writeHandler(const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t bytes_transferred, std::shared_ptr<std::string> message, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>::iterator> it)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            std::cout << "Write handler error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            this->disconnect();
            delete this;
            return;
        }
//....
```

Notice the `delete this;` in the write handler.

So when there is an error while sending the data, the session will disconnect and then delete itself. However, there is a segmentation fault after `writeHandler` has returned. Could it be because I am deleting `this` although it is captured in `async_write`?

Comment: I know, however I am not accessing it anymore in "my" code. So I thought that it is maybe accessed by `async_write`, after `writeHandler` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Once you `delete this` any access to the object is invalid. It doesn't matter if you've copied/captured the pointer anywhere else.

Comment: I wrote an answer to your comment under my question: 
 
I know, however I am not accessing it anymore in "my" code. So I thought that it is maybe accessed by async_write, after writeHandler returns

Comment: It is. `this` is bound in the bind: `boost::bind(&Session::writeHandler,
           this`. You're accessing it in your code. And it gets executed asynchronously by the completion handler, because you asked it. Use the enable_shared_from_this pattern seen in all the samples.